# PostSharp Class-Aspect to add aspects to all members of the class

Tags: c#, postsharp, aspect

Is there a way to mark a Class with an attribute, that will add attributes to all methods?

For Example:

```
[TestAspect]
public class Test
{
    public void foo() { ... };

    [AttributeA]
    public void bar() { ... };
}
```

Now the TestAspect should make it so, that Aspects are added to bar().

I've by writing an `AspectProvider` class, the following should apply AspectA and AspectB to all methods of the class, which have the AttributeA.

```
[Serializable, AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
public class TestAspect : TypeLevelAspect, IAspectProvider
{
    private static readonly CustomAttributeIntroductionAspect aspectA =
     new CustomAttributeIntroductionAspect(
        new ObjectConstruction(typeof(AspectB).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes)));

    private static readonly CustomAttributeIntroductionAspect aspectB =
    new CustomAttributeIntroductionAspect(
        new ObjectConstruction(typeof(AspectA).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes)));

    public IEnumerable<AspectInstance> ProvideAspects(object targetElement)
    {
        Type targetClassType = (Type)targetElement;

        foreach(MethodInfo methodInfo in targetClassType.GetMethods())
        {
            if(!methodInfo.IsDefined(typeof(AttributeA), false))
            {
                yield break;
            }
            yield return new AspectInstance(targetElement, aspectA);
            yield return new AspectInstance(targetElement, aspectB);
    }
}
```

But the Attributes are not applied to the Methods unfortunately? No exception or error is thrown.

Does someone have an advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following Code I was able to at least add 1 Custom Attribute to the methods that are decorated with `AttributeA` in my Class, which is marked with `TestClass`.

```
[Serializable, AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = false)]
public class TestClassAttribute : TypeLevelAspect, IAspectProvider
{

    public IEnumerable<AspectInstance> ProvideAspects(object targetElement)
    {
        Type type = (Type)targetElement;

        return type.GetMethods().Where(method => method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AttributeA), false)
                .Any()).Select(m => new AspectInstance(m, new CustomAttributeIntroductionAspect(
                    new ObjectConstruction(typeof(AttributeB).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes)))));
    }
}
```

Comment: Using CustomAttributeIntroductionAspect and IAspectProvider is the right approach to this problem. You can also find a related sample at this link: https://samples.postsharp.net/f/PostSharp.Samples.AutoDataContract/